# Objects behind other objects show through in camera view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, transparency

Blender 3.0 and 2.93.6 - same issues in both.
User vs. Camera Perspective

This issue is only in Camera Perspective:
I have images as planes surrounding two image textured cubes (one as a pyramid) - all with pngs as their textures. In Camera perspective, any object will show through any and all objects between it and the camera. This is true for the Viewport solid mode, material preview mode, and display render mode for Evee. Cycles shows nothing at all - just gray.

I added a plain red cube to see if there was an issue with the PNGs. Same thing with the cube - anything behind it shows through. Nothing appears with Cycles.

I've searched and adjusted to various Alphas and Opaque - no difference to the issue.
Clip start and end are set to .0001 m & 6000 m.

When I render a still (F12), the render shows the same issue as the Camera perspective.

All the above was done via the Layout view. When I went into shading view and zoomed the view back/out the foreground images would flicker and I can find distances where I can get some or all of an object to appear. Weird. It has nothing to do with clipping that I can see. But maybe I'm missing something here.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Glenn
[image: User View]
[image: Camera View]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Hi Chris - Thanks for looking into this. I don't see a way to upload a file so I'm putting the file up on google drive. Here's the link:

Comment: That didn't work. Trying the link again. Let me know if the OneDrive link below doesn't work for you. I don't see a way to upload the actual file.
[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao_SodCMjMy0vlG7ePz3qzejkKIs?e=PBBIme)

Comment: you totally messed up your camera clip range. change it to 0.1 (start) and 1000 (end) and it works

Comment: Wow. Right. I had the start/end #s backwards. Basic clipping issue. Thanks for pointing me back to something I'd checked several times. Noob 101.

Comment: No problem. I still make every mistake at least 3 times again…‍♂️